# Why does the accuracy drops everytime right after loading and continue training of a ConvNet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I train an InceptionV3 ConvNet from scratch with my own data. After reloading a model and continuing learning, I realized that the accuracy of the training set drops slightly right after reloding (e. g. from 0.956 to 0.879). Then the accuracy continues to behave as I expect it to. It seems very unintuitive to me. Does anyone have an idea why that might be?

This is how I originally initialized the model:

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights=None, include_top=False)

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# Freeze all layers
if preTrained:
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I use the following callback to store the model after each epoch:

`checkpointEveryEpoch_callback = ModelCheckpoint(saveDir + "modelFiles/saved-model-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, mode='max')`

And this code for reloding the model (I do not compile the model again):
`model = load_model(oldModelPath)`

I tried the same using RMSProp optimizer. But the same happens after reloading and continuing training.

Any ideas why accuracy of the training set drops slightly every time?